# Como reducir el numero de iteraciones para satisfacer una propiedad?

Tags: python

Necesito optimizar el código para reducir el tiempo de ejecución en determinado servidor, de manera que funcione para un límite de `<= 10**6` ya que para cantidades menores ha funcionado correctamente pero tengo problemas a medida que va incrementando.

Ejemplo: `1325` sus dos primeros dígitos forman un primo (`13`) el cuadrado seria `1325**2 = 1755625` el cual tiene `17` que también es un numero primo y finalmente los dos últimos dígitos de cada uno son iguales (`25`). Sabiendo que `a` y `b` determinan el rango como puedo encontrar los que cumplan con estas cualidades sin exceder el tiempo de ejecución para grandes cantidades?

```py
def resolver(a, b):
    cnt = 0
    primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

    for num in range(a, b+1):
        if int(str(num)[:2]) in primes:
            sq_num = num**2
            if int(str(sq_num)[:2]) in primes and str(sq_num)[-2:] == str(num)[-2:]:
                cnt+=1      

    return cnt
```

Comment: No entiendo el ejemplo. ¿Cuáles serían los valores de `a` y `b`? ¿Y el valor del resultado esperado? Dicho esto, 2 posibles mejoras que se me ocurren son almacenar los primos como un `set` ya que el operador `in` sobre los sets es O(1) mientras que el mismo operador sobre listas es O(n). La otra mejora sería guardar los primos como strings (`primes = {'2', '3', ...}`), ya que siempre que quieres hacer la comparación haces un *cast* de str a int, si fuesen strings ese paso te lo puedes ahorrar (`int(str(num)[:2]) in primes` -> `str(num)[:2] in primes`, idem para la otra comprobación)

Comment: `a` y `b` es el rango de valores para hallar dichos numeros, por ejemplo `a=2, b=1200` devuelve unicamente `1176`, eso lo tengo resuelto, pero cuando el rango aumenta, digamos `a=2, b=10**6` e intento enviar la respuesta el servidor me devuelve error ya que excede el limite de tiempo de ejecucion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera en la que puedes reducir la cantidad de iteraciones es ajustar tu algoritmo para iterar solamente por los números que cumplen la primera condición.

Si hay 25 números primos del 1 al 100, automáticamente has eliminado el 75% de las iteraciones necesarias para encontrar los resultados.

Para lograrlo, digamos con los números entre 100 y 1000, puedes iterar por la lista de números primos, convertir estos en los primeros dos dígitos de un número, multiplicándolo por 10 y sumandole los números entre el 0 y el 9.

Por ejemplo, con el número primo 37, obtendríamos:

```
37 * 10 + 0 = 370
37 * 10 + 1 = 371
37 * 10 + 2 = 372
...
37 * 10 + 9 = 379
```

Ojo, que la definición del problema, a través del ejemplo que colocas, es imprecisa, pues tienes números primos que se componen de un único digito, pero siempre tomas dos dígitos del número para comparar, con lo que no me queda claro si los primos de 1 dígito deben ser excluidos por definición, o si hay que mejorar el algoritmo.

Por estas razones, y algo de falta de tiempo, no escribo una rutina completa, pero si una muestra de cómo podrías implementarla basándote en este principio.

La rutina del ejemplo toma solamente el número mayor, siempre busca entre 1 y este número. Además, este número, por definición, debe ser una potencia de 10. Si no lo es, tomará la potencia de 10 de la misma longitud como número máximo. Es decir, si pasas 78756, buscará entre 1 y 10000.

Para mantener simple el algoritmo, hace una llamada recursiva para buscar los números de la potencia de 10 anterior al parámetro de entrada.

Toma en cuenta que el algoritmo resultante es bastante imperfecto, es solo una muestra de como implementar la idea mencionada. Sigue sin tomar en cuenta correctamente los números primos con un solo dígito y no procesa los números en orden, por lo que si los imprimes, seguro para un humano haría falta ordenarlos primero.

```
def buscarEspeciales(max):
    cnt = 0
    primos = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
    
    rango = 10**len(str(max // 1000));
    if rango > 100:
        cnt += buscarEspeciales(max//10)

    for primo in primos:
        for x in range(0, rango):
            numero = primo * rango + x
            sq_num = numero**2
            if int(str(sq_num)[:2]) in primos and str(sq_num)[-2:] == str(numero)[-2:]:
                cnt+=1 
                #print(numero)
    return cnt
    
    
total = buscarEspeciales(1000000)
print(total)
```

Otro *error* de este algoritmo es que algunos números se van a repetir, por ejemplo el número 3701, se obtiene de estos dos cálculos:

```
37 * 100 + 1   = 3701
3 * 1000 + 701 = 3701
```

Hay que especializarlo para procesar correctamente estos casos.

Comment: Puedes deducir si este problema es basado en alguna base teórica sobre este tipo de *minimización*?. Tales como las que son usadas para procesar números primos de diferentes maneras, podría servirme de ayuda para complementar tu código

Comment: Mi idea no es encontrar una respuesta especifica ya que para los próximos programas a resolver debería de tener el conocimiento necesario para realizar dicha tarea, por lo tanto generalmente empezar por aprender *determinado* concepto.

Comment: quizás pueda relacionarse https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Erat%C3%B3stenes a lo que me refiero

Comment: no veo la relación entre ambos..

Answer (score 0):

Pensé que lo que podría hacer un poco más lenta la ejecución era la búsqueda en la lista `primes`, ya que se tiene que hacer varias veces por número. Entonces hice varias pruebas:
(1) Cambiando `*elemento* in primes` por muchos bloques `if num == 2: return True`, luego para `num == 3`, `num == 5`, etc.
(2) Similar al anterior, pero en vez de solo `if`, usando `if/elif/else`.
(3) Un solo `if` con multiples condiciones `... num == 5 or num == 7 or ....`

En todas las pruebas el rendimiento fue peor que el código original, lo cual deja de lección que Python es extremadamente eficiente buscando elementos en listas.

Donde si hubo una mejora apreciable fue convirtiendo la lista de primos a cadena.

```py
def resolver(a, b):
    cnt = 0
    primes = '11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97'

    for num in range(a, b+1):
        if str(num)[:2] in primes:
            sq_num = num**2
            if str(sq_num)[:2] in primes and sq_num%100 == num%100:
                cnt+=1
    return cnt
```

El código original de la pregunta:

```
print(resolver(2, 1000000)) 
# Resultado: 2549 | Tiempo Prom: 0.4940 seg
```

El código de esta respuesta (numeros primos como cadena):

```
print(resolver(2, 1000000)) 
# Resultado: 2549 | Tiempo Prom: 0.2265 seg (~~ 2.18x más rápido)
```

[Nota] Se eliminaron los primos de 1 dígito ya que no tiene sentido tenerlos. Esto es porque solo existen 2 cuadrados enteros de 1 dígito (4 y 9) y ambos son obviamente distintos a su raíz, por lo que esto: `str(sq_num)[-2:] == str(numero)[-2:]` nunca se cumplirá para `num^2 < 10`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! la idea de usar el operador `mod` o porcentaje (`%`) puede ser muy eficaz, puedes agregar alguna manipulación de **bits** para este algoritmo?